# Create file using template.erb

Tags: ruby, erb, chef-infra

I am fairly new to ruby and chef, I wanted to know if there is a way to create a file using a template? I tried searching about it but couldn't find much stuff. Am try to create a blacklist file and insert some regex into it via chef. So I wanted to add the attributes and use a `template.erb` to create the file while running chef. Any hints, pointers?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Chef has special resource named [template](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Resources#Resources-Template), to create files from templates. You need to put your template inside cookbook under templates/default directory and then use it in your recipe, providing the variables.

**cookbooks/my_cookbook/templates/default/template.erb :**

```
# template.erb
A is: <%= @a %>
B is: <%= @b %>
C is: <%= @c %>
```

**cookbooks/my_cookbook/recipes/default.rb :**

```
template "/tmp/config.conf" do
  source "template.erb"
  variables( :a => 'Hello', :b => 'World', :c => 'Ololo' )
end
```

Comment: @Draco: Have one question. So here, I need to create the file in the recipe right? I mean the code fl00r had written, should that go in the recipe?

Comment: No. You need not anything besides, what I have written.  `cookbooks/my_cookbook/recipes/default.rb` - is a recipe.

Answer (score 6):

```
require 'erb'
class Foo
  attr_accessor :a, :b, :c
  def template_binding
    binding
  end
end

new_file = File.open("./result.txt", "w+")
template = File.read("./template.erb")
foo = Foo.new
foo.a = "Hello"
foo.b = "World"
foo.c = "Ololo"
new_file << ERB.new(template).result(foo.template_binding)
new_file.close
```

So `a`, `b` and `c` now availible as a variables in your template

I.E.

```
# template.erb
A is: <%= @a %>
B is: <%= @b %>
C is: <%= @c %>
```

Result =>

```
# result.txt:
A is Hello
B is World
C is Ololo
```

Comment: So, just to clarify, the class has to be a ruby file right? `rb`?

Comment: Well, `can` means? I wanted to know the right way to do it. So.. :)

Comment: I am not sure about Chef, so if Chef recipes are written in Ruby, you can put this class right inplace with other stuff, like rendering erb. Or you can create a new file with a class, so don't forget to require it before use.